# Replace default Nant task by different one

Tags: .net, nant, nantcontrib

I want to redefine copy task from Nant without changing my .build configuration files. Is it possible in nant?

Msbuild has:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="SGen" AssemblyFile="Tools\Extensions.dll"/>
```

which can do that.

I wrote my copy task by don't know how to override it globally during nant script execution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything like that in nant. Nant can call other nant scripts via the [nant task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/nant.html). You could write a little nant build file with your different copy methods in it and call out to it whenever you want to do a copy. Use a property and the `if` and `unless` attributes to select which copy implementation you want.